# Failed to make a jar file outside JDK_HOME

Tags: java, jar

I am studying Java Web Start and JNLP. The problem is in making a jar file. When i saved my .class file at location C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin and access this location through command prompt and by using this command 
"jar cvf WelcomeApplet.jar *.class"
my jar file will perfectly made but when i make a folder in bin directory and access that folder through this command "cd C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\WelcomeApplet" and after that i used this command for making the jar file
"jar cvf WelcomeApplet.jar *.class"
it didn't works and my command prompt give me this message..
"'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
How can i solve this problem....

Comment: One normally does not work inside the JDK directory. It is nice seeing a bare-bones approach: use an environment variable JAVA_HOME and use it in the search path env var PATH = ...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin. Then you can work from everywhere. Or use an IDE, like from netbeans.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

command to make a jar file in a different directory

```
jar cvf program.jar -C path/to/classes .
```

That assumes that path/to/classes contains the com directory.

Step 1: Go to directory where the classes are kept using command prompt (or Linux shell prompt)
Like for Project.

```
C:/workspace/MyProj/bin/classess/com/test/*.class
```

Go directory bin using command:

```
cd C:/workspace/MyProj/bin
```

Step 2: Use below command to generate jar file.

```
jar cvf helloworld.jar com\test\hello\Hello.class  com\test\orld\HelloWorld.class
```

Using the above command the classes will be placed in a jar in a directory structure.

Comment: Probably `../jar ...` too. As jar exe not found

Comment: i didn't understand it kindly give me the full command for accessing that folder and make a jar file in that folder.